# Unable to adjust the label alignment in rave reports from delphi

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, rave-reports

I am using delphi 10.2.2 and Nevrona Rave Reports11.
I want to adjust the labels alignment on rave reports from delphi code at runtime.
I tried using the setparam but it dint help me.
Can anyone help me on this?